# recvfrom does not receive anything from the client, but the client is sending the info

Tags: networking, c, sockets

So I wanted to make sure I am not missing something and I have the concepts clean in my head.

This is the part of the code I have:

```
UDP_Msg mensajeRecibidoUdp;
struct sockaddr_in c_ain;
sock_udp=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
struct sockaddr_in c_ain;
socklen_t tam_dir;    

while(1)
{
  if(recvfrom(sock_udp, &mensajeRecibidoUdp, sizeof(UDP_Msg), 0,
      (struct sockaddr*) &c_ain, &tam_dir) <0)
 ....
```

The problem is that it waits for a message to arrive. And the message is sent, but this code does not get anything, it doesn't unfreeze.

It's a simple exercise, and the client is already built. It gets the port from a file, then sends a UDP_Message that is a struct with a couple ints and an array (the client already knows the IP and port).

I thought the way I handle the buffer could be wrong, but every example I've seen uses it like that. I also thought that the c_ain variable might needed to be initialized, but that's not the case if I understand it properly. So I don't get why the process gets... blocked, not sure what's the proper word, and since a lot of time passes by, an alarm goes off and the process gets killed (because it should have got info and keep with the code but it did not).

I can add lots of other info, I tried to keep it short. I kind of know that call is the one that isn't working properly because of how it behaves when I run the client-server thingy.

Edit: Bind:

```
 bzero((char*)&dir_udp_serv,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));              
  dir_udp_serv.sin_family=AF_INET;
  dir_udp_serv.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(HOST_SERVIDOR);
  dir_udp_serv.sin_port=0;              
  fprintf(stderr,"SERVIDOR: Asignacion del puerto servidor: ");
  if(bind(sock_udp,
      (struct sockaddr*)&dir_udp_serv,
      sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))<0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"ERROR\n");                
      close(sock_udp); exit(1);
    }
```

Second edit: I just realized I have two binds in the code. The idea is I create two connections on the same server, one for UDP and one for TCP. So I made the same steps for both UDP and TCP. From the answer I got I realize that might be wrong. Would it be only 1 bind per socket, even if I create two sockets, one for UDp and one for TCP?

The above does not seem to be the case.

Also, I don't know what more details should I add, but the server and client are both on the same computer so their address are both 127.0.0.1, but that's expected and I believe does not change anything as to why the server does not get the info sent from the client.

Answer (score 3):

Ask yourself: on which port do your clients send their messages? Where is that port in your server code? *Nowhere*. You forgot to bind your local socket to your local address (and port) :

```
struct sockaddr_in local;
local.sin_family = AF_INET;
local.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
local.sin_port = htons(PORT); // Now the server will listen on PORT.

if(bind(sock_udp, (struct sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(local)) < 0){
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
}

// Now you may call recvfrom on your socket : your server is truly listening.
```

Note that you only need to bind once. No need to put this in a loop.

Comment: As I said I didn't write all of the code because I thought it'd be an annoyance, later on I realized the bind is kind of important. I do have it in the code, this is what I have and I think it's pretty similar, I'll add it to the main post since comments can't hold so many characters ok?

Comment: @keont but you're binding to port 0, which means (AFAICR) that the kernel will pick a _random_ port.  You really need to pick a specific port, per this answer.

Comment: It's more normal to use the `INADDR_ANY` macro than `inet_addr("0.0.0.0")`

Comment: @keont It isn't 'pretty similar' at all. Your code binds to (a) a specific IP address, which restricts inbound connectivity, and (b) port zero, which gives you a system-allocated port. Unless you have special manual steps to see what it was and adjust the client accordingly, it cannot possibly work. Try it JohnWHSmith's way.

Comment: @EJP well, it's not unusual to want to bind to a specific IP address, and if the OP's `HOST_SERVIDOR` is set to `0.0.0.0` then it'll bind to all interfaces correctly.  It's really only the port setting that's an issue.

Comment: Allright I'm afraid you guys have to explain it to me more slowly, I am not understanding. Yes, I specify port to 0, I get a random port, I assign it with :

getsockname(sock_udp, (struct sockaddr *)&dir_udp_serv, &len);

I thought that was ok.

Second and more important: What is that about restricts inbound connectivity, I'm afraid I didn't understand it.

Answer (score -1):

Allright not sure if this is the place, but the answer to my own question was one expected: The server was listening in a port, and the client was sending to a different one. That was because of the way the port assigned was sent to the client: in my case, without transform it to network format (ntohs()), so when the client did htons(), the number was a completly different one.

Comment: Sending the port to the client isn't shown in your code, and only raises the same question again in reverse. The server needs to know the client's port number to send its own port number to the client. Somewhere this has to stop and an initial port number has to be coded, instead of just using port zero.

Comment: That's... I'm not sure if you know, but if the client connects to you, you can store info from who is connecting to you. In recvfrom, that's what the 5th parameter is... you store that info so you can freely send to him whatever you want... And again, no one is using port 0, when you use 0 you get a random port, that you can later on know which one was with getsockname(). So what I'm saying is, either I don't understand what you are saying, or you're missing the point and downvoting me without being right.